# Dynamic line counts in Codemirror gutter is empty every second time the key is pressed

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes, ui-codemirror

I was tasked to build a note input area where i should show line count and character count in each line. I chose codemirror to do it. Everything works but the Line character count seems to be blanking out every second key press. I have attached video link to the issue and the code is pasted below. 
Thank you

[Video of issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S2Jn5riwS40U4NWwRUQBmLOvVfpDaiT2/view?usp=sharing)

```
var count;
var textEditor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('noteArea'), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  autofocus: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "lineLength"],
  lineWrapping: true
});

textEditor.on("cursorActivity", function(cm, change) {
  var doc = cm.getDoc();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  count = 50 - cursor.ch
  var line = cursor.line
  var info = cm.lineInfo(line);
  cm.setGutterMarker(line, "lineLength", info.gutterMarkers ? null : makeMarker());

  function makeMarker() {
    var marker = document.createElement("div");
    marker.style.color = countColor(count);
    marker.innerHTML = count || "●";
    return marker;
  }

  function countColor(count){
    if (count < 0 ) {
      return "#822"
    } else {
      return "green"
    }
  }

  // var line = doc.getLine(cursor.line);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is this line:

```
cm.setGutterMarker(line, "lineLength", info.gutterMarkers ? null : makeMarker());
```

**Solution**:

If you want the marker to always be the result of `makeMarker()`, just remove the ternary:

```
cm.setGutterMarker(line, "lineLength", makeMarker());
```

**Explanation:**

What the original line does is:

- If `info.gutterMarkers` is **falsy** (e.g. `null`) then this line will call `setGutterMarker` to set this line's marker to the result of `makeMarker()` (e.g. `<div>50</div>`).
- If `info.gutterMarkers` is **truthy** (e.g. `<div>50</div>`), then this line will call `setGutterMarker` to set this line's marker to `null`.

Since `info.gutterMarkers` *is the marker for the current line* (that is, it's modified every time you call `setGutterMarker`), that line is toggling between the two cases (first the marker is falsy, so it sets it to `<div>50</div>`, then the marker is truthy, so it sets it to `null`, then the marker is falsy, so it sets it to `<div>48</div>`...). That's what causes the alternating behavior you observed–the gutter marker is set to `null` every second press.

Comment: Can you please guide me to the correct directions on this issue please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289031/codemirror-gutter-marker-change-issue