# Codemirror gutter marker change issue

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I have a requirement where i need to show line character counts in every line. I am showing it in gutter like such

[image]

The limit on each line is 112, so the gutter number goes to negative when user types more than 112 characters. Everything works great. But when i do copy paste it doesn't work. The line is identified from the copy/paste texts and everything just the gutter marker which shows line character counts doesn't show.

I have a little video demo of the behavior, and code posted below.

**[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DghjEzEfdI2p1OYXl9FKMka529qJEGgQ/view?usp=sharing)**

```
// Instantiate CodeMirror
var textEditor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('noteArea'), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  autofocus: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "lineLength"],
  lineWrapping: true,
  fixedGutter: true,
  lineWiseCopyCut: true,
  dragDrop: true,
  lineSeparator: '\n'
});

// Logic to check character length in one line. This function also displays the number of characters on the left
textEditor.on("change", function(cm, change) {
  var doc = cm.getDoc();
  var cursor = doc.getCursor();
  var count = 112 - cursor.ch
  var line = doc.size -1
  var info = cm.lineInfo(line);
  cm.setGutterMarker(line, "lineLength",makeMarker(count, line));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `on("input"` instead of `on("change"`? The `"input"` event fires for a lot of cases that the `"change"` event doesn't (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

Comment: input didn't work, they have inputRead which didn't work either :(

Comment: I fixed it by getting all the line and looping through them